# How to redirect to private route dynamically after social media login in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have normal and social media login options on my page, and I have created a private Route as in https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow. 
The problem is that after redirecting to for example google and back, the state of the Router history is gone.
I have created a workaround in which I store the previous URL in local storage, when the user visits the login screen.

Do you guys have any better idea on how to save History state?

Comment: I may not give you a code solution, but i have a live app that has a google login passport, and sign up, login, https://github.com/EliHood/fullstacktypescript but this can give an idea.

Answer (score 0):

**I think the main issue is that you're not persisting the data.**

Start off by creating a service that checks for the current user. You can persist this data in localstorage, and upon logout it should clear out the credentials.

I did an implementation like this in my previous side project.

https://github.com/EliHood/fullstacktypescript

I have something like ...

```
export function* getAutoLoginStatus(action) {
    try {
        const login = yield call(api.user.currentUser);
        const token = login.token;

        if (login.user.googleId !== null) {
            localStorage.setItem("googleId", login.user.googleId);
        }
        setAuthToken(token);
        sessionData.setUserLoggedIn(token);
        yield put(actionTypes.getUserSuccess(login));
    } catch (error) {
        localStorage.clear();
        yield put(actionTypes.getUserFailure(error.response.data.message));
    }
}
```

This saga is getting called on nav component, this checks to see if user is logged in or not.

```
 componentDidMount() {
   this.props.getUser();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using react-router-dom, you install it by going to your project folder on command line and put:

```
npm i react-router-dom
```

Go to your App.js file and import the following:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
```

Then at your App.js file, you should render something like:

```
render(){
return (
  <div className="App">
   <Router>
    <Route path="/" exact component={() => <[YourHomeJSXComponent]/>} />
    <Route path="/anotherPage"  exact component={()=> <[AnotherJSXComponent]/>}/> 
   </Router>
  </div>
);
}
```

Then, when you want to redirect to another page, you simply put the following command:

```
window.location.assign("/anotherPage");
```

And voila, every location.assign will register an entry on your navigation history.